# Why can't I access the elements of this object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a simple hobby project after finishing a Udemy course on web development, and I'm having some issues with a simple middleware I've written.

The function in question goes as follows:

```
const User = require('../models/user.js');

const middleware = {
    checkIfAdmin: function checkIfAdmin(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            User.find({"username": "jemorgan"}, (err, foundUser) => {
                console.log(foundUser._id);
                if (err) {
                    req.flash("error", "Something went wrong");
                } else if (foundUser._id === req.user._id) {
                    console.log("Going next");
                    next();
                } else {
                    console.log("going back");
                    req.flash("error", "You don't have permission to do that.");
                    res.redirect("back");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

module.exports = middleware;
```

When I ran the code without the `console.log`, evaluating the final else branch regardless of whether or not I was logged in as the correct user. I threw in the `console.log` to try to troubleshoot, and found that `user._id` was `undefined`. Strangely, when I remove the `.id` and simply call `console.log(user)`, I get the following:

```
[
    {
        _id: 5ef5c1adfc196d47107679ce,
        username: 'jemorgan',
        ...
    }
]
```

I feel like there must be something simple here that I'm missing. My troubleshooting leads me to believe that the `User.find()` function is locating the correct document in the database, and that `foundUser` is a reference to the correct object. Yet when I try to access elements of that object, I'm being told they're undefined, even  though I can clearly see that the object does have those elements.

To keep this brief, I'm not showing the whole project here, but if anyone wants context, the project is hosted on [my github](https://github.com/josephemorgan/groovie).

Thanks for any tips that you might habe.

Comment: You need to use .findOne in your case when you want to find a specific document. .find returns an array of results that match the query.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

Comment: I'm not at my computer to try this, but I'm certain that it's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks so much! Please feel free to copy/paste this as an answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are querying through Mongoose using .find and not [.findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne), it's easy to confuse the two but the first one will always return an array of documents that matched the query while the second will return the first object it finds according to the query. When querying emails/ids etc. you should use findOne.

Answer (score 1):

In your example :

```
let user=[
    {
        _id: 5ef5c1adfc196d47107679ce,
        username: 'jemorgan',
        ...
    }
]
```

since user is an array so you can't access `user._id` , Instead you should `user[0]?._id`